# Commmand line command to copy entire directory (including directory folder) to another directory

Tags: windows, command-line

using the command line, I'd like to copy one directory to another. For example there is directory `C:/test` and `C:/test2`.

I'd like to copy `C:/test` into `C:/test2` so that the result will be `C:/test2/test`

Everything I've found so far will only copy the files and folders contained in `C:/test` into `C:/test2`, but leaves out the parent directory.

Comment: try to use xcopy

Answer (score 67):

Try using `XCOPY` with the `/E` switch. More info [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/99.cfm).

I haven't had to access this information from my brain in ***years***!

**UPDATE**

The documentation says that it copies all files and subdirectories from the source directory (meaning that the parent directory is not created), so you would have to create `test` in `C:\test2` first and then use `XCOPY`.

Comment: The '/T' switch on Xcopy will do a directory & subdirectory structure copy without any files.

Comment: RE: `/T` switch, that can be extremely useful sometimes. Granted, it does not come up often, but when it does, wow does knowing that trick come in handy! :)

Comment: Better use `robocopy /CREATE /COPYALL /DCOPY:T src dst` to just copy the folder and empty files but preserve all timestamps and other attributes.

Comment: This actually does not provide answer for the question because folder `test` still nees to be created.

Comment: @IGRACH I thought `md test` and then using `xcopy` was trivially obvious.

Comment: Well question is about `copy` folder not creating new folder and then copying contens in it.

Comment: @IGRACH rather pedantic distinction, no?

Comment: @vivin No that is the point. When you want to copy `c:\users\me\New movie that is the best` to drive `e:`  you would have to cleate `New movie that is the best` on drive `e:` instead just copy whole folder like you can do  with windows explorer.

Comment: @IGRACH Ok. But it appears 34 people (not counting myself) seem to think that it is rather obvious one would have to create the destination directory first. I mean, the docs pretty much say that. I've updated the answer either way.

Comment: `xcopy /s /e /c /h /k /y {source} {destination}`

Comment: I miss linux's `cp -r`.

Comment: A trailing backslash after destination folder name actually creates it in process: 
xcopy /e {source} {destination}\
So the complete solution for the OP's question would be `xcopy /e {source} {destination}\{source_folder_name}\ `

Answer (score 43):

```
xcopy c:\test c:\test2\test /s /e /h
```

Here is info on XCOPY [[1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx),[2](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)]

Comment: How to stop asking me to input "D"?

Comment: @YumYumYum: You can use the /I switch: "  /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory."

Comment: this shows me a list of files but doesn't copy anything. any idea why ?

Comment: You actually want to use the /i switch (i as in island) not /l (l as in land) - I think you accidentally used /l (lowercase L) instead of /I (uppercase i) as this font shows how difference between the two!

Answer (score 33):

Use `ROBOCOPY` if you're creating backup scripts. `xcopy` has been deprecated and will likely be phased out of use in the near future. `robocopy` can do everything `xcopy` can. It is also more flexible and reliable. Creating scripts with `robocopy` will future-proof them.

---

1. Use robocopy to easily copy folders. The robocopy command replaces the xcopy command. It can quickly copy entire folders without having to worry about defining the contents. For example, to copy all of the contents of the C:\tools directory to the new folder D:\backup\tools, enter the following:

   ```
    robocopy C:\tools D:\backup\tools /e
   ```

   The /e modifier tells robocopy to include all subdirectories. This includes empty folders.
   robocopy will automatically copy hidden and system files. It will create new directories if they don't exist at the target location.
2. Mirror a directory. Mirroring a directory is great for making backups. The mirror option of robocopy will copy all of the contents from the source to the destination. It will then delete anything at the destination that doesn't exist at the source. This ensures that your backup only has the latest versions of your files. For example, to mirror C:\Users\My Documents to D:\backup\My Documents, enter the following:[4]

   ```
    robocopy "C:\Users\My Documents" "D:\backup\My Documents" /mir
   ```

   This function will preserve all permissions of the original files.
3. Enable restarting. You may want to include the ability to restart the process in case the connection is severed mid-copy.

   ```
    robocopy "C:\Users\My Documents" "D:\backup\My Documents" /z
   ```
4. Log the copying process. robocopy allows you to create a log file. This can help you pinpoint problems or generate an archive of what's been copied.

   ```
    robocopy "C:\Users\My Documents" "D:\backup\My Documents" /log+:<filename>.txt
   ```

   The /log+ modifier will append the existing log file instead of overwriting it. If you'd prefer to just overwrite the old log file, use /log:.txt.

Comment: Please explain where `robocopy` is deprecated.  It's 2023-11-16 my shell is `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2715]` (windows 11 pro).  My `robocopy /?` output doesn't SEEM to indicate anything about deprecation.  Please explain `deprecated` in this answer.

Comment: @ebyrob The answer says xcopy is deprecated and that you should use robocopy instead. Not that robocopy is deprecated.

Comment: @Pooks Thank you and thank goodness I didn't down-vote!  I really need to get glasses I think...

Answer (score 10):

I recommend [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) over [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), as it has a lot more options, including keeping timestamps intact, which I find essential.

Robocopy needs to be added on XP/2003, but it is standard from Vista onwards.

I actually usually use [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/), but the 64-bit version is not free.

Comment: `robocopy` is a Windows program. The question was about DOS.

Comment: @grawity: The likelihood of him actually using 16-bit DOS is very small compared to the high probability of him calling CMD 'DOS', as is common in the real world.

Comment: the real question is: is robocopy a Microsoft program?

Comment: @knocte yes it is

Answer (score 5):

```
XCOPY SourceDrive: DestinationDrive: /S /E
```

For example, if you need to copy `E:` drive data to `H:` drive (external hard drive) through command line or from xboot command environment.

```
xboot:\>XCOPY E:\ "H:\BackupFolder\" /S /E
```

Comment: /S is not required when /E is present. http://www.windows-commandline.com/copy-directory-command-line/

Answer (score 3):

If the original question is what I have been looking for an answer to then I, and obviously no one above, has come up with a clear solution.

What I am looking for is to copy the test directory into the test2 directory without having to type it in again. Something like

```
xcopy /isvy c:\test d:\test2
```

where `d:\test2\test` does not exist before the copy but does after. This would save on miss-typing test the second time in the destination path. The above command will copy all the files and any directories into test2 but will not create the test directory.

So far

```
xcopy /isvy c:\test d:\test2\test
```

is really the only way I have found to get this job done. Again if you have typing issues there is no guarantee that the source and destination directories will match.

An alternative to correct this is

```
set mydir=test&&xcopy /isvy c:\%mydir% c:\test2\%mydir%
```

This sets the destination directory in the `mydir` variable then uses that variable in both the source and destination path. If you type the variable wrong you will either get an error or the destination directory will probably have `%` at the beginning and end.

It is longer to type but less chance of getting the wrong names. They will be noticeable.

Comment: It's actually `xcopy /ievy c:\test d:\test2\test` to keep directory tree structure, and in `set mydir=test&xcopy /isvy c:\%mydir% c:\test2\%mydir%` only 1 **&** will suffice, since the result of setting a value is always successful.

Answer (score 2):

```
xcopy SWITCHES SOURCE DESTINATION
```

Where `SWITCHES` can be:

- To copy the whole directory structure:

  `/hiev`
- To overwrite files in destination (in case destination folder already exists):

  `/hievry`
- To overwrite and also copy with ACL+Attribute:

  `/hievxok`

**Most suited to your case:**

`xcopy /hievry C:\test C:\test2\test`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this by using PowerShell `Copy-Item` function

```
Copy-Item 'C:/test' 'C:/test2' -Recurse -Force
```

It will copy all files and folders while preserving folder hierarchy. `-Force` overwrites the destination if already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I needed to copy a number of folders including the folder names to a destination location, and hoped this question marked answered would help, but it truly does not.

Firstly, there are definitely occasions where one would need this ability and I ran into one when I had to copy folders from C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC_MSIL. Windows Explorer refuses to show this folder, so you have to use a command prompt.

If you are familiar with the GAC folder, you would know that the folder names are non-trivial and easy to get wrong if you mistype.

So creating the directory beforehand is not really an option - unless you use a script - which I ended up using, as this was the only real solution.

First dump the folders you want to copy to a temporary file, this is usually based on some pattern e.g.

```
dir /B policy* > Folders.txt
```

Then loop over the entries in the dump and copy to destination. Xcopy will take care of creating a folder if you end the destination argument with a backslash (\)

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Folders.txt) do xcopy /E /S %%A C:\Dest\%%A\
```

Put both these commands in a batch file and run.

Now if only xcopy or robocopy has this built in.

Answer (score 0):

XCOPY SourceDrive: DestinationDrive: /S /E

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain this? (especially the `/S /E` flags)

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a functional alternative answer for your question.

Firstly, using `FORFILES` with `/S` parameter, confers that every sub-directory in `C:\test` will be reached.

Secondly, with `/C` parameter, it is possible to start a chain of commands with native variables, which makes possible to create the identic directories at the destination, and THEN copy the files to inside them, using two conditional structures.

The first conditional structure `@isdir==TRUE` (make sure to use capital letters), allows to get directories only from source, then creating them at the destiny with `MKDIR [path]\@relpath` at the end.

Finally, the second one makes sure that it are working with files only with `@isdir==FALSE`, and then the COPY command simply gets the job done, getting all files reached by FORFILES command, setting `[path]@relpath` as destination, to copy the files to inside the just created directories.

```
forfiles /s /c " cmd /c ( if @isdir==TRUE mkdir C:\test\@relpath ) && ( if @isdir==FALSE copy @file C:\test2\@relpath)"
```

Hope that helps everyone around here.

Answer (score -3):

This will do that from the GUI, don't know how they do it.

"...small program will allow you to select the "from directory" and "into directory", and it will proceed to copy ONLY the directory structure."

http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/treecopy/