# Files accessibles on MS-DOS, absent on Windows explorer, how to get them?

Tags: windows-explorer, ms-dos

I have USB Drive that contains interesting files. When I acces it using Windows Explorer, I get only a bunch of *.tmp files. But when I acces it using MS-DOS, I can get to my precious directory F:\Dossiers.

How can I solve this problem ? I am unable to **copy** the directory to another computer drive. I get `the specified file is unfound` !!!!

Is there a solution ? I know it is because of a kind of virus ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using this command : xcopy to copy my whole directory to my hard drive.

thank y ou to this question : 
[Commmand line command to copy entire directory (including directory folder) to another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/206036/dos-command-to-copy-entire-directory-including-directory-folder-to-another-dir)