# Copy Folder in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, robocopy, xcopy

How can I copy folder in windows cmd. I would like to copy folder it self with files in it, not just files. When you use `copy` or `xcopy` commands they copy files but not folder name. `xcopy folderOne folderTwo` copy files in `folderOne` to `folderTwo`. Is there a way to copy `folderOne` to `folderTwo`, so the folder structure will be `folderTwo\folderOne`.

This is easily done in windows explorer just by selecting folder and copy/paste to another destination.

I came from this question [Commmand line command to copy entire directory (including directory folder) to another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/206036/commmand-line-command-to-copy-entire-directory-including-directory-folder-to-a/206037][1]). There seams to be no right answer to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following command should do what you're trying to accomplish:

```
xcopy folderOne folderTwo\folderOne /i /s
```

Comment: As I set your are creting new drive, folderTwo\folderOne. I would like to copy whole folder/dir, not to create new one.

Comment: @IGRACH That's exactly what you asked for in your question ...