# How to copy one directory to another with window command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, robocopy, xcopy

I read alot of guides about to copy directories. On SO also read the posts

1. [Commmand line command to copy entire directory (including directory folder) to another directory](https://superuser.com/questions/206036/commmand-line-command-to-copy-entire-directory-including-directory-folder-to-a/206037)
2. [copying all contents of folder to another folder using batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601161/copying-all-contents-of-folder-to-another-folder-using-batch-file)

but nothing is working for me. I am using Window 10 Pro 64bit version. My directory looks like

```
myfolder
   |
    ---folder1
    ---folder2
         |
         ---sample.txt
```

The expected output is

```
myfolder
   |
    ---folder1
         |
         ---folder2
             |
             ---sample.txt
    ---folder2
         |
         ---sample.txt
```

At command prompt, my present working directoy is

```
C:Users\MyName\Desktop\myfolder>
```

When I tried with belows

```
robocopy folder2 folder1 /COPYALL /E
xcopy folder2 folder1 /s /i
```

only ***sample.txt*** was copied to folder1. What's I am wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Only sample.txt was copied to folder1

You need to properly specify the target directory name.

Use one of the following commands:

```
robocopy folder2 folder1\folder2 /COPYALL /E
```

Or:

```
xcopy folder2 folder1\folder1 /s
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.

Answer (score 2):

xcopy copies only content of folder2 to folder1. You should try this, as now you are under myfolder:

`cd folder1
 xcopy ..\folder2 folder2 /S /I`

Answer (score 1):

Either of the above would work. 
My preference is to user wildcards, where appropriate.

xcopy /s folder2\* folder1\